# Update values of a column in a table when a value from another table changes

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `TABLE_1` and `TABLE_2`.

`TABLE_1` contains `ID` and `NAME`, where `ID` is a primary key.

`TABLE_2` contains `ID` and `DATA`, where `ID` and `DATA` form a compound primary key.

1. I'm looking for a SQL query that updates the `ID` in `TABLE_2` when they are changed in `TABLE_1`.
2. How can I create this table structure?

**TABLE_1**

```
ID      NAME
100     LLL
101     KKK
102     JJJ
```

**TABLE_2**

```
ID      DATA
100     HHHHHHH
100     MMMMMMM
100     ZZZZZZZ
101     IIIIIII
101     FFFFFFF
102     EEEEEEE
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need to do this, but anyway.

One way to do this is to use [foreign key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html), available in the InnoDB storage engine:

```
CREATE TABLE `TABLE_1` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `TABLE_2` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DATA` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`DATA`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) 
    REFERENCES `TABLE_1` (`ID`) 
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The above table structure will update all the matching `ID` from `TABLE_2` whenever an `ID` in `TABLE_1` is modified (`ON UPDATE CASCADE`). Also, whenever you delete an `ID` from `TABLE_1`, all the matching entries from `TABLE_2` will also be deleted (`ON DELETE CASCADE`). Because of this constraint, the `ID` from `TABLE_2` has to exist in `TABLE_1` for an `INSERT` to complete successfully.

Also keep in mind that foreign keys affect performance, but without knowing exactly why you want such a thing, I cannot suggest any better solution.

Comment: @user1370390: Make sure to accept answers, and welcome to Stack Overflow.